# Keep getting the error "undefined method `post_comment_url' for #<CommentsController" when trying to render comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to programming and have been learning Ruby on Rails for about six weeks now.

I'm trying to add "comments" functionality to a page in my app that displays a post (post#show). I'm rendering two partials in my /posts/show.html.erb file - one that displays the comments form (_form.html.erb) and the other that displays all the comments for the post (_comment.html.erb). The form is rendering just fine, but when I try and render the _comment.html.erb partial, I get the following error:

````
**NoMethodError in CommentsController#create**
**undefined method `post_comment_url' for #<CommentsController:0xacfb188>**

Extracted source (around line #11):



    if @comment.save
         flash[:notice] = "Comment was created"
          redirect_to [@post, @comment]
       else 
         flash[:error] = "Comment failed to save"
       end


```app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:11:in `create'
````

This is the create method in the posts controller:

```
    def create
     @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
     @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
     @post.topic = @topic
     authorize @post
      if @post.save
       flash[:notice] = "Post was saved."
        redirect_to [@topic, @post]
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end
```

And this is the create method in the comments controller -

```
def create  
   @post =  Post.find(params[:post_id])
   @comment = current_user.comments.build(params_comment)
   @comment.post = @post
   authorize @comment

   if @comment.save
     flash[:notice] = "Comment was created"
      redirect_to [@post, @comment]
   else 
     flash[:error] = "Comment failed to save"
   end
  end
```

This is my posts/show.html.erb fiLe:

```
<h1><%= markdown @post.title %></hi>

<div class="row">  
<%= image_tag(@post.image.thumb.url) if @post.image? %> 
  <div class= "media">
    <small>
    <%= image_tag(@post.user.avatar.tiny.url) if @post.user.avatar? %>
    submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> ago by
    <%= @post.user.name %> 
    <p><%= @post.body %></p>
    </small>
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <% if policy(@post).edit? %>
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_topic_post_path(@topic, @post), class: 'btn btn-success' %> 
      <% end %> 
     <%= render partial: 'comments/form', locals: { post: @post, comment: @comment } %>
     <%= render partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { post: @post, comment: @comment } %> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is the _comment.html.erb partial:

```
<%= form_for [post, comment] do |f| %>
  <p><%= @comments.each do |comment| %></p>
  <p><%= @comment.body %>
  <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

**rake routes** shows this for comments:

```
   post_comments POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)         comments#create
```

The error shows that I'm not redirecting correctly (and I've tried several different ways), but with rake routes showing post_comments, I'm not certain what else to redirect to. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your route is defined as `post_comments` (note the plural). Therefore change `post_comment_url` to `post_comments_url`.